# Delete Replicates from the first column

Tags: excel, vba

i am looking for a way to delete rows in a column that countains replicates in the first column. The function RemoveDuplicates doesnt seems to work properly , do you have any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: What columns are you referring to?

Comment: The first one (column A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this on internet. works great.
deleting duplicate rows based on a column of cells that I highlighted.

```
    Public Sub DeleteDuplicateRows()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' DeleteDuplicateRows
' This will delete duplicate records, based on the Active Column. That is,
' if the same value is found more than once in the Active Column, all but
' the first (lowest row number) will be deleted.
'
' To run the macro, select the entire column you wish to scan for
' duplicates, and run this procedure.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim R As Long
Dim N As Long
Dim V As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
On Error GoTo EndMacro
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set Rng = Application.Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, _
ActiveSheet.Columns(ActiveCell.Column))
Application.StatusBar = "Processing Row: " & Format(Rng.Row, "#,##0")
N = 0
For R = Rng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
If R Mod 500 = 0 Then
Application.StatusBar = "Processing Row: " & Format(R, "#,##0")
End If
V = Rng.Cells(R, 1).Value
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Note that COUNTIF works oddly with a Variant that is equal to vbNullString.
' Rather than pass in the variant, you need to pass in vbNullString explicitly.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If V = vbNullString Then
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng.Columns(1), vbNullString) > 1 Then
Rng.Rows(R).EntireRow.Delete
N = N + 1
End If
Else
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng.Columns(1), V) > 1 Then
Rng.Rows(R).EntireRow.Delete
N = N + 1
End If
End If
Next R
EndMacro:
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
MsgBox "Duplicate Rows Deleted: " & CStr(N)
End Sub
```